# Помогите найти ошибку в функции lua

Tags: lua

Здравствуйте. Имеется вот такая функция:

```
function s:checkpos(x, y)
    for _, o in pairs(self.objects) do
        if o.x == x and o.y == y then
            return o
        else return nil end
    end
end
```

где **objects** - это таблица с другими таблицами в которых есть значения под ключами **x** и **y**. Цикл for почему-то не перебирает все элементы
таблицы, а останавливается на первом с координатами 50, 50.
В то же время другая функция:

```
function s:update(dt)
    for _, o in pairs(self.objects) do
        if o.update then
            o:update(dt)
        end
    end
end
```

работает как полагается, т. е. для каждого элемента таблицы вызывается функция **update**, если она есть.
Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку!

Comment: А в чём ошибка заключается? Приведите, пожалуйста, её текст. Зачем в функции checkpos цикл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сами пишете `return` после первой итерации. Если Вам нужно найти объект с нужными координатами, то код должен быть такой

```
function s:checkpos(x, y)
  for _, o in pairs(self.objects) do
    if o.x == x and o.y == y then
      return o  // если нашли - выходим
    end
  end
  // если дошли сюда, значит пробежали весь цикл и не нашли. Тогда возвращаем nil
  return nil  
end
```

Comment: Спасибо, долго писал, не заметил.